# In R, compute time series difference of lagged values

Tags: r

Hello my dataframe looks like this for a very large number of years and products:

```
product<-c(1,2,3)
yr1<-c(109,213,30)
yr2<-c(613,488,125)
yr3<-c(729,494,127)
df<-data.frame(product,yr1,yr2,yr3)
```

I need to transform it so that the values for the years after the first are the difference of the current value and the previous (lag) value, so that it looks like this:

```
yr2<-c(504,275,95)
yr3<-c(116,6,2)
df<-data.frame(product,yr1,yr2,yr3)
```

With 613-109=504, 729-613=116, etc.

How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`dplyr` option with `cur_data` which makes a copy of the data to substract every column with its previous column:

```
library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  mutate(cur_data()[,c(-2)] - cur_data()[-ncol(.)]) %>%
  mutate(product = df$product)
```

Output:

```
  product yr1 yr2 yr3
1       1 109 504 116
2       2 213 275   6
3       3  30  95   2
```

Comment: Good solution, @Quinten! You can still shorten it: `library(dplyr)
df %>% 
  group_by(product) %>%
  mutate(cur_data()[-1] - cur_data()[-ncol(.)])`.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
df[,tail(grep("yr",colnames(df)),-1)]-df[,head(grep("yr",colnames(df)),-1)]

  yr2 yr3
1 504 116
2 275   6
3  95   2
```

Comment: Thanks! Not sure why, but the other two solutions didn't work with my original dataset. Perhaps because there were two  other columns in the dataframe that did not follow the format of this data.

Answer (score 1):

Another `dplyr` approach:

```r
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
 mutate(yr1 = NULL, across(-product, ~ .x-df[which(cur_column() == names(df))-1]))

#>   product yr1 yr2
#> 1       1 504 116
#> 2       2 275   6
#> 3       3  95   2
```